# I made a custom image slider and there is a weird error with the image shaking

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser, cross-platform

My slider works on all browsers/computers, except for safari on one person's computer.
This is the strange error (starts around 7 seconds in):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoNWkT7MDJQ&feature=youtu.be

What could cause this strange inconsistency between computers/browsers?

Thank you!

Edit: here is code

JS:

```
    setInterval(wells_fancy_slider, 130);
    t = null;
    timeout_variable = null;


})

function wells_fancy_slider() {
    if (!paused) {
        if(style=='day'){
            if (parseInt($('.building_container').css('left')) < -2200) {
                $('.building_container').css('left', '+=4000');
            }
            if (parseInt($('.building_container2').css('left')) < -2200) {
                $('.building_container2').css('left', '+=4000');
            }
        }else{
            if (parseInt($('.building_container_night').css('left')) < -2200) {
                $('.building_container_night').css('left', '+=4000');
            }
            if (parseInt($('.building_container_night2').css('left')) < -2200) {
                $('.building_container_night2').css('left', '+=4000');
            }
        }

        $('.building_container_night').css('left', '-=' + speed);
        $('.building_container_night2').css('left', '-=' + speed);

        $('.building_container').css('left', '-=' + speed);
        $('.building_container2').css('left', '-=' + speed);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wells_slider.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wells_slider.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container">
            <img id="night_sign" src="img/full_night.png"/>
            <img id="day_sign" src="img/full_day.png">
            <!-- day -->
            <div class="building_container">
                <img class="building b1" id="b1" src="img/buildings/b1.png" width="250" height="250"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/living/culture/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusives-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb1" ><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b2" id="b2" src="img/buildings/b2.png" width="180" height="240"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/woman/shoes-bags/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusive-akris-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb2"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b3" id="b3" src="img/buildings/b3.png" width="180" height="230"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/woman/jewelry-watches/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusive-luisaviaroma-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb3"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b4" id="b4" src="img/buildings/b4.png" width="155" height="240"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/woman/fashion/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusive-moncler-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb4"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b5" id="b5" src="img/buildings/b5.png" width="180" height="240"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/woman/fashion/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusive-marni-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb5"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b6" id="b6" src="img/buildings/b6.png" width="180" height="240"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/living/culture/holiday-gift-guide-2012/">
                    <div class="popover pb6"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b7" id="b7" src="img/buildings/b7.png" width="180" height="240"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/woman/fashion/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusive-versace-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb7"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b8" id="b8" src="img/buildings/b8.png" width="180" height="240"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/woman/jewelry-watches/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusive-cartier-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb8"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b9" id="b9" src="img/buildings/b9.png" width="150" height="280"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/woman/shoes-bags/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusive-smythson-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb9"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b10" id="b10" src="img/buildings/b10.png" width="250" height="250"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/woman/fashion/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusive-the-webster-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb10"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
                <img class="building b11" id="b11" src="img/buildings/b11.png" width="150" height="230"/>
                <a href="http://www.lifestylemirror.com/man/style/lifestyle-mirror-lifestyle-avenue-exclusive-brooks-brothers-boutique/">
                    <div class="popover pb11"><div class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</div></div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share some code if it's not a secret. It's powered by jQuery?

Comment: Yes it's powered by jQuery, I'll show you something soon

Comment: Sorry, you could not strip it down to the essentials? there where the issue starts to happen?

Comment: I took out a lot of code.  It's not really a code issue though.  It's more of a web browser/design issue.  It works on all browsers but then the thing in the video starts happening randomly, not even on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider this an answer by any means, but SO won't let me add a comment with my current reputation, but please take a look at this page:

http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-jquery-image-scroller/

This seems to be what you are trying to accomplish but in a different way. It's worked great for me in the past and the code is explained rather well. Maybe you could use this or use some ideas from it to help with your project.

Using this, you could split your image into, say 5 - 10 parts then scroll through them adding the begging images to the end to reset the slider. This is explained pretty clearly in the article above.

As for why it's glitching out like that with your code, I frankly have no clue. Sorry I can't answer your question more directly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I might have started with that, but at this point, I don't have time to re-implement.  It's either fixing my code or it's not going to the client tomorrow morning.  Oh well :\

Comment: Ah, I understand. I wish I could be of more help to you then. Trust me, I know how it is. Wish the best of luck to you!

Comment: Thanks!  I'm hoping it was just the one computer that the error happened on.  Like I said, works everywhere except 1 computer with 1 browser.  UGH